# How to keep parentheses of elements in LISP when using function 'append'?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to create a function *grouper (L1 L2)* which has two lists as arguments. These two lists are composed of elements like '(1 2 3)' and '(4 5 6 )'. The function *grouper* returns a list like this : ((1 4)(2 5)(3 6)) .

Here's my code :

```
    (defun grouper1 (l1 l2)
      (setq l (list (car l1) (car l2)))   ;;; initialization of symbol 'l'
      (loop
        (setq l1 (cdr l1))
        (when (null (car l1)) (return l))
        (setq l2 (cdr l2))
        (setq l (append l (list (car l1) (car l2))))
      )
    )
```

Like what I've mentioned before, i expect the output list looks like : ((1 4)(2 5)(3 6)). But what i actually gets is (1 4 2 5 3 6). I don't really understand where do those parentheses go and how can i have them in the output.

Comment: Your variable `l` is undefined. Use `let` to define local variables. If you append two lists, then you get a list back. If you want an element of the list to be a list itself, then you need an additional call to `list`. Also make sure your function returns a result.

Comment: If you got that right, then you might think how you can solve that much simpler with the function `mapcar` without `setq`, `car`, `cdr`, `append`, `loop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use standard formatting.  See e. g. [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code).

```
(defun grouper1 (l1 l2)
  (setq l (list (car l1) (car l2)))   ; initialization of symbol 'l'
  (loop
    (setq l1 (cdr l1))
    (when (null (car l1)) (return l))
    (setq l2 (cdr l2))
    (setq l (append l (list (car l1) (car l2))))))
```

Contrary to what you seem to mean with your comment, `setq` is not specified to initialize a variable.  Use `let` to introduce local variables.

```
(defun grouper1 (l1 l2)
  (let ((l (list (car l1) (car l2))))
    (loop
      (setf l1 (cdr l1))
      (when (null (car l1)) (return l))
      (setf l2 (cdr l2))
      (setf l (append l (list (car l1) (car l2)))))))))
```

Your problem is that you `append` the partial lists, i. e. make a single list of them.  `(append (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` is `(1 2 3 4)`.  Instead, you should collect them.  Another issue with `append` is that it is inefficient in a loop, because you create quadratic runtime for an essentially linear operation.  A useful idiom, when doing this “manually”, is using `push` and `nreverse`.  Finally, you always create the first pair, even if the first input list were empty.  You should only collect in the loop, not during initialization.

```
(defun grouper1 (l1 l2)
  (let ((l ()))
    (loop
      (when (endp l1)
        (return (nreverse l)))
      (push (list (car l1) (car l2)) l)
      (setf l1 (cdr l1)
            l2 (cdr l2)))))
```

What should happen when `l2` is empty?  If it should terminate as well, then you can also use the extended loop construct to help with the list management:

```
(defun grouper1 (l1 l2)
  (loop :for x1 :in l1
        :and x2 :in l2
        :collect (list x1 x2)))
```

Or you can just use `mapcar`:

```
(defun grouper1 (l1 l2)
  (mapcar #'list l1 l2))
```

If you actually only want to terminate when `l1` is at an end, and collect `nil`s when `l2` is shorter, then you'd have to add padding for these last two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If to collect `nil` from shorter list and collect all elements of longer list (tail recursive form):

```
(defun grouper2 (l1 l2 &optional (acc nil))
  "Group elements of l1 and l2, continue till end of longer list and 
collect `nil` from shorter."
  (cond ((and (null l1) (null l2)) (nreverse acc))
        (t (grouper2 (cdr l1) (cdr l2) (cons (list (car l1) (car l2)) acc)))))
```

And a variadic version (for as many lists as you want):

```
(defun grouper3 (&rest lists)
  "Group any number of lists collecting all elements from the longest list 
and collecting `nil` from shorter lists."
  (let (result)
    (labels ((grouper-helper (&rest lists)
               (cond ((funcall #'every #'identity (mapcar #'null lists))
                      (nreverse result))
                     (t
                      (setf result (cons (mapcar #'car lists) result))
                      (apply #'grouper-helper (mapcar #'cdr lists))))))
      (apply #'grouper-helper lists))))
;; I used local variable `result` to store what I actually would store in an 
;; optional variable `acc`, due to the reason that `&rest` and `&key` interfer
;; in capturing the arguments...
```

A variadic version where the shortest list determines the length of the
returned list (longer lists are truncated):

```
(defun grouper4 (&rest lists)
  "Group any number of lists collecting all elements from shortest list."
  (let (result)
    (labels ((grouper-helper (&rest lists)
               (cond ((funcall #'some #'identity (mapcar #'null lists))
                      (nreverse result))
                     (t
                      (setf result (cons (mapcar #'car lists) result))
                      (apply #'grouper-helper (mapcar #'cdr lists))))))
      (apply #'grouper-helper lists))))
```

Or using one of @Svante's definitions for `grouper1`:

```
;; you need flatten
;; either alexandria:flatten or:

(defun flatten (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((atom (car l)) (cons (car l) (flatten (cdr l))))
        (t (append (flatten (car l)) (flatten (cdr l))))))

;; or tailrecursive:
(defun flatten (l &key (acc nil))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((atom (car l)) (flatten (cdr l) :acc (cons (car l) acc)))
        (t (flatten (cdr l) :acc (append (reverse (flatten (car l))) acc)))))


(defun grouper4 (&rest lists)
  (mapcar #'flatten (reduce #'grouper1 lists)))
```

Maybe shorter, but a macro (not a function):

```
(defmacro grouper4 (&rest lists)
  `(mapcar #'list ,@lists))
```